# $_POST working, but $_GET method not working

Tags: php

I am learning php and in this small code I am sending data to a php application using post method. it works fine and displays the result.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>learn php</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <form action="htmltophp.php" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="value_to_test"/>
            <input type="submit" value="button"/>


        </form>


    </div>
</body>
```

here is the code for the php application

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

      $value = $_POST['value_to_test'];
      echo $value;
    ?>

    <p>testing</p>
</body>
```

But when the method is changed to GET, it does not work the same way. it does not echo the value. it only show the html 'testing'.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show the code you used for `GET` method?

Comment: Try print_r($_GET); on htmltophp.php @Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are passing  form method="get" and receives it as $_GET. If form is submitted correctly with get then you can see the form elements value as key pair in your query string.

Answer (score 1):

Change below line code for the php application:

```
 $value = $_POST['value_to_test'];
```

to

```
 $value = $_REQUEST['value_to_test'];
```

`$_REQUEST` by default, contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`

If I had to choose, I would probably not use `$_REQUEST`, and I would choose `$_GET` or `$_POST` -- **depending on what my application should do** (i.e. one or the other, but not both) : generally speaking :

- You should use `$_GET` when someone is requesting data from your application.
- And you should use `$_POST` when someone is pushing (inserting or updating ; or deleting) data to your application.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `get` method then user `$_GET` in php

PS: `$_REQUEST` also useful when you don't know about request method

```
 <?php

      $value = $_REQUEST['value_to_test'];
      echo $value;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $_REQUEST['value_to_test'];
```

or you can try:

```
echo $_GET['value_to_test'];
```

but that will only work if you actually do a test. In any case, I recommend you check out [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).